# ActiveMq: Exceeded the maximum number of allowed client connections

Tags: java, c#, .net, activemq-classic

In my .Net application all components are interacting with ActiveMQ but after processing few messages, it starts giving error:

"**Could not accept connection : org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.ExceededMaximumConnectionsException: Exceeded the maximum number of allowed client connections.**".

I have increased maximum number of connection in web config but its not working.
I heard that for this scenario you should use **PooledConnectionFactory**.
Can you guys please suggest how we can implement PooledConnectionFactory or is there any other alternative of it.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: I have configured 10 connections in the configuration file of ActiveMQ and using only 2 connections.   Although I am disposing connections from my client  application  but getting "Exceeded the maximum number of allowed client connections" exception after some time .  Not able to figure out where it is consuming 10 connections. Any way through which we can check how may connections server is having right now  where ActiveMQ is installed  ??

Comment: I am using Apache.NMS dll in my .Net application and maximumConnections is SET to 1000 but in Active MQ console screen in Connector openwire section i can see only 100 connection . Then why i am getting this exception.  Need suggestion . Thnx

Answer (score 4):

First of all you can configure how many connections the broker will accept in the brokers transport connector configuration, e.g. in your activemq.xml

```
<transportConnectors>
  <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

1000 connections should be the default limit configured in the Apache distribution of ActiveMQ. 
Unless you have an unexpectedly low limit you are probably leaking connections in your client application, which should be easy to verify using commands like netstat.

I am not the ActiveMQ NMS expert but to my knowledge there is no PooledConnectionFactory for .NET

http://activemq.apache.org/nms/msdoc/1.6.0/vs2005/Output/html/N_Apache_NMS.htm

This is only available for Java.
The previous reply is right, you should try to re-use existing connections into the broker. Connection creation is considered a heavy operation. Re-creating connections each time is an anti-pattern and leaking connections would of course be a bug.

Comment: Can you please tell in which case this error generally comes or what are the areas that i need to look in to resolve this error. Its not coming on regular basis but every once or twice in a week its reproducing.

Comment: You should be able to use netstat or similar os level commands to check how many connections you have into the broker at any point in time. If that number reaches the configured maximumConnections limit in your broker config, you will get that error. Based on this try to find out what client(s) may open more connections than expected and inspect their code to analyse how they could be changed to re-use connections across many messages.

Comment: I am using Apache.NMS dll for ActiveMQ. Can we check that client has reached maximum connection limit. and then can we release /reset connection ?

Answer (score 3):

Try reuse your Connection somehow when producing messages. Like, keep an open connection around rather than open/close for each message.

There is a CachingConnectionFactory provided in [Spring.NET](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net) that may simplify this task.

Comment: Do I need to implement this CachingConnectionFactory in server side where my  ActiveMQ exists ??  .

Comment: No client side. The idea is to not reestablish a connection per message, but to reuse the existing connection as much as possible. From client.

Comment: First of all i am not creating connection again and again . In case of error i am disposing it also.  Gone through Spring.NET but i am not able to figure out how to implement CachingConnectionFactory  in my application. Do you have another other link that demonstrate this thing.